# alert ajax post method response from asp.net controller method in ajax success or in done function

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I need to pass json response from controller method in case record created successfully and want to alert this message in ajax in success function or in done but I failing to achieve this for some reason.

### javascript

```
  $('#NewFunctionNavigationForm').submit(function (e) {

   e.preventDefault();

  var DataToPost =  JSON.stringify($('#NewFunctionNavigationForm').serializeObject());

  var formURL = $(this).attr("action");

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: formURL,
      dataType: "JSON",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: DataToPost,
  })
.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { alert("Success: " + response); })
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("Error"); })
.always(function (jqXHROrData, textStatus, jqXHROrErrorThrown) { alert("complete"); });

});
```

### controller method

```
#region CreateNewFunctionNavigation
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateNewFunctionNavigation()
    {

        return PartialView("CreateNewNavigation_Partial");
    }
    #endregion

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateNewFunctionNavigation(CreateFunctionNavigation_SP_Map model )
    {


        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                 _FN_Services_a2.CreateFunctionNavigation(model);

                 return Json(new { Response = "Success" });


            }
            catch (DataException ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable To Create New Function Navigation" + ex);
            }
        }
        return PartialView("CreateNewNavigation_Partial", model);
        //return Json(new { Url = Url.Action("CreateNewNavigation_Partial", model) });

    } //end
```

Comment: So what is actually happening?

Comment: no alert been called on submit form however record is creating successfully

Comment: i want return Json(new { Response = "Success" }); from controller to be alert in done function of $.ajax{...}

Comment: Are you sure your hitting the `return Json(new { Response = "Success" });` line in the controller? You also have a problem because if `ModelState` is not valid you return html, but the ajax call specifies `dataType: 'json'` so that would cause an error. And `response` does not exist in the ajax call. It would need to be `alert("Success: " + data.Response);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting your done function should work. Try below code:

```
.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { alert("Success: " + data.Response ); })
```

Let me know if you face any problem.